# List of key descriptions such as <esc> or <cr>

Tags: key-bindings

I am looking for a complete list of the key descriptions commonly used for remapping keys.

Comment: PROTIP: `:help key` followed by Ctrl+D

Comment: You can refer nathangrigg.net for the vim pdf. That has the entire list of key descriptions. This PDF is extracted from all help contents of vim editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:help key-notation
```

They are described in the [help](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation).

```
notation    meaning         equivalent  decimal value(s)    ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Nul>       zero            CTRL-@    0 (stored as 10) *<Nul>*
<BS>        backspace       CTRL-H    8 *backspace*
<Tab>       tab         CTRL-I    9 *tab* *Tab*
                            *linefeed*
<NL>        linefeed        CTRL-J   10 (used for <Nul>)
<FF>        formfeed        CTRL-L   12 *formfeed*
<CR>        carriage return     CTRL-M   13 *carriage-return*
<Return>    same as <CR>                *<Return>*
<Enter>     same as <CR>                *<Enter>*
<Esc>       escape          CTRL-[   27 *escape* *<Esc>*
<Space>     space                32 *space*
<lt>        less-than       <    60 *<lt>*
<Bslash>    backslash       \    92 *backslash* *<Bslash>*
<Bar>       vertical bar        |   124 *<Bar>*
<Del>       delete              127
<CSI>       command sequence intro  ALT-Esc 155 *<CSI>*
<xCSI>      CSI when typed in the GUI       *<xCSI>*

<EOL>       end-of-line (can be <CR>, <LF> or <CR><LF>,
        depends on system and 'fileformat') *<EOL>*

<Up>        cursor-up           *cursor-up* *cursor_up*
<Down>      cursor-down         *cursor-down* *cursor_down*
<Left>      cursor-left         *cursor-left* *cursor_left*
<Right>     cursor-right            *cursor-right* *cursor_right*
<S-Up>      shift-cursor-up
<S-Down>    shift-cursor-down
<S-Left>    shift-cursor-left
<S-Right>   shift-cursor-right
<C-Left>    control-cursor-left
<C-Right>   control-cursor-right
<F1> - <F12>    function keys 1 to 12       *function_key* *function-key*
<S-F1> - <S-F12> shift-function keys 1 to 12    *<S-F1>*
<Help>      help key
<Undo>      undo key
<Insert>    insert key
<Home>      home                *home*
<End>       end             *end*
<PageUp>    page-up             *page_up* *page-up*
<PageDown>  page-down           *page_down* *page-down*
<kHome>     keypad home (upper left)    *keypad-home*
<kEnd>      keypad end (lower left)     *keypad-end*
<kPageUp>   keypad page-up (upper right)    *keypad-page-up*
<kPageDown> keypad page-down (lower right)  *keypad-page-down*
<kPlus>     keypad +            *keypad-plus*
<kMinus>    keypad -            *keypad-minus*
<kMultiply> keypad *            *keypad-multiply*
<kDivide>   keypad /            *keypad-divide*
<kEnter>    keypad Enter            *keypad-enter*
<kPoint>    keypad Decimal point        *keypad-point*
<k0> - <k9> keypad 0 to 9           *keypad-0* *keypad-9*
<S-...>     shift-key           *shift* *<S-*
<C-...>     control-key         *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
<M-...>     alt-key or meta-key     *meta* *alt* *<M-*
<A-...>     same as <M-...>         *<A-*
<D-...>     command-key (Macintosh only)    *<D-*
<t_xx>      key with "xx" entry in termcap
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The Num Keys are different (for normale mode):

```
nmap <Esc>Oq 1
nmap <Esc>Or 2
nmap <Esc>Os 3
nmap <Esc>Ot 4
nmap <Esc>Ou 5
nmap <Esc>Ov 6
nmap <Esc>Ow 7
nmap <Esc>Ox 8
nmap <Esc>Oy 9
nmap <Esc>Op 0
nmap <Esc>On .
nmap <Esc>OQ /
nmap <Esc>OR *
nmap <Esc>Ol +
nmap <Esc>OS -
nmap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

Use `inoremap` for insert mode.